# Usage of STL algorithm functions on more then one dimensional containers

Tags: c++, stl

I have a simple struct

```
struct Point
{
    Point(int x, int y)
        : x(x)
        , y(y)
    {}
    
    int x, y;
};
```

And a two dimersional vector(it also can be a three dimensional vector or more)

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> v(10, std::vector<Point>(10, Point(3, 4)));
```

And I want to know the summary of all x values.
I can use std::accumulate and it would look like

```
int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [](int init, const auto& vec)
  {
    return init + std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, [](int init, Point p)
    {
        return init + p.x;
    });
  });
```

or I can write a simple double for

```
for (const auto& vec : v)
{
    for (const auto& p : vec)
    {
        sum += p.x;
    }
}
```

And it looks more readable(imo).
What should I change to make the usage of std::accumulate has better readability? Or it's not applicable in such case. Is it applicable in general to use STL when you have more then one dimensional container?

Comment: Multi-dimensional `std::vector`s are a bit inefficient, you might be better off using a single dimensional vector with a wrapper class which implements the indexing for you, that would simplify the use of std algorithms too

Comment: Having multi-dimentional containers is just a way to represent data. IMO data that belongs together should normally be in the same container. If you need a multi-dimentional representation of that data you can do that and still store the data in a single vector.

Comment: *What should I change to make the usage of std::accumulate has better readability?* IMHO, nothing.  I know there is advice out there that says don't use raw loops, but IMHO a ranged based for loop is not a raw loop.  It expands out to using the iterators and the variable is the actual current element so there is no mistake about which item you are using.  In cases like this they make the code much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah, using C++11 standard, a ranged based for loop seems to be the best way. But range-v3 from C++20 looks awesome and let it make as a single line with "accumulate" word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the STL as it stands now, then a nested range-for loop is *probably* the most readable (though it's still subjective).

However, I am very much an advocate of not using range-for loops, unless you need a `transform` or a `for_each`. If the code is doing an `accumulate`, then you should write an `accumulate`.

Here's how I would write this code today, with the help of range-v3. Before long, the STL will let you write code that's as readable.

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

int sum = rs::accumulate(v | rv::join, 0, std::plus{}, &Point::x);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9xmXV3).

Comment: Omg. I coudn't imagine it can be written in one line with "accumulate" word. Range-v3 is a really big one step towards clear and readable code. And if you need to accumulate three demension vector | rv::join should be added. That is incredible.